# Variable in function that can be used outside?

Tags: c++

Basically, I want to ask for a variable using `cin >> num` in a specific function, and then use that `num` variable inside a different function. But when I try to do that, it says that the variable does not exist, so I'm assuming whatever I assign inside a function only stays there.

Is there any way to create a variable that can be used globally? I've heard of global variables, and stuff like that, but I don't really know anything about them, so if that's the best solution, please let me know how to do that!

### Edit 1:

Here is the code for what I'm trying to do:

```
void ordered_leaders() {
    // ... some code bla bla ...
    int maze_num;
    cout << "Please enter the maze number: ";
    cin >> maze_num;
    // ... some more code ...
void fill_leader() {
    ifstream file("MAZE_" + to_string(maze_num) + "_WINNERS.txt");
```

### Edit 2:

I decided to take the advice of @largest_price_is_(...) (as I'm not familiar with classes yet) but unfortunately I need that maze number for more than 1 different function and whenever I use the `maze_number` function it asks the maze number again and again as I'm calling it several times across functions... any way to fix that? Basically at the moment is is whats happening:

### Edit 3:

```
int main() {
    leaders( maze_numb() );
    ordered_leaders( maze_numb() );
    fill_leader( maze_numb() );
}
```

so as you can expect is asks for the `maze_num` three times.
I can send the whole code if it makes anyone understand the problem better.

Comment: ***Is there any way to create a variable that can be used globally?*** Yes however this is considered a bad practice and make your program harder to understand when it reaches thousands of lines of code spread out in hundreds of source files.

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/What-are-global-variables-in-Cplusplus 
You can use global variables

Comment: Your question would be better and we could offer better help if you included a [mcve]

Comment: @DevDaemon Global variables are a very bad idea in general, so no, that's not a good recommendation.

Comment: Maybe you want to use a class for your maze instead of free functions.

Answer (score 1):

At your current stage I advise you to stay away from global variables. They may appear like a solution to you, but their downsides are numerous.

Instead you should learn how to pass parameters to functions and use return values. I can only outline some very basic example here and have to rely on you to read more in books.

```
#include <iostream>

void read(int& num){
    std::cin >> num;
}

int read2() {
    int x;
    std::cin >> x;
    return x;
}

void print(int y){
    std::cout << y;
}

int main() {
    int num;
    read(num);
    print(num);
    // or
    int num2 = read2();
    print(num2);
}
```

`read` takes a reference to an `int`. The modifications made to the reference inside the function are visible to the caller on the passed argument. `read2` takes a different approach by returning the read value. In `main` you can then pass that variable to `print` to print its value. Note how `print` takes the variable by value (no reference), so if we would modify `y` in `print` this would have no effect on `num` in `main`.

---

For your example that is:

```
int ordered_leaders() {
    int maze_num;
    cout << "Please enter the maze number: ";
    cin >> maze_num;
    return maze_num;
}

void fill_leader(int maze_num) {
    ifstream file("MAZE_" + to_string(maze_num) + "_WINNERS.txt");
}

int main() {
    fill_leader( ordered_leaders() );
}
```